# GraphiQL Parameter Default Value

Tags: c#, parameters, graphql, default, graphiql

I am seeing some strange behaviour with the default value of a query parameter using GraphQL and GraphiQL in C#.  Here's the query I have created:

```
FieldAsync<ListGraphType<PartitionedCountGraphType>>("partitionedCounts",
description: "Returns counts of the meter reads partitioned by ranges of id values..",
arguments: new QueryArguments(
    new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>>
    {
        Name = "partitionInterval",
        DefaultValue = 100000,
        Description = "Specifies the size of group that the meter reads should be divided into (e.g. 100000)."
    }),
resolve: async context =>
{
    return await GetPartitionedCountsAsync(context);
});
```

As you can see, I have supplied a default value of 100,000 for the *partitionInterval* parameter.  However, when I use the GraphiQL Explorer UI to build the query, it suggests a default value of 10:

[image]

If you run the query, a value of 10 is not accepted for this parameter as it is too low.  How do I get GraphiQL to use the default that I have suggested when building the query or at least not supply a default at all when building the query from the Explorer?

I am using C# for .Net Core 3.1, the GraphQL NuGet package v4.6.1 and the GraphQL.Server.Ui.GraphiQL Nuget v4.4.1.

Comment: Supply it as a variable `partitionInterval: $partitionInterval` then don't actually pass it in

Comment: Charlieface, Yes I am using variables when I call the query from code but my concern is more when testers / users run queries via the GraphiQL UI.  In that situation, the UI is proposing a default value that is too low.

Comment: It should do that automatically so I suggest you file a bug  report